# What does JS do in Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

```
cmp %al, %cl
js x
```

I'm confused on what the js (jump on sign) is doing. Is it saying that if al is positive and cl is negative vice versa then jump?

Also, what happens if `%cl` is 0?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`JS` will jump if the sign flag is set (by an earlier instruction). [CMP](http://web.itu.edu.tr/%7Eaydineb/index_files/instr/cmp.html) will always modify the flags by performing a subtraction, in this case `%cl - %al`.
(This is AT&T syntax, so `cmp %cl, %al` is the same as Intel syntax `cmp al, cl`)

Because of the operand-size of the instructions, the sign will be bit 7 of the expression `%cl-%al` (which is thrown away; EFLAGS is updated just like `sub`, but not `al`.)

If `al == 0`, then the temporary value will be `cl` exactly and the sign will be the sign of the register `cl`. Thus a jump is taken if `cl` is negative.

Here's a [reference](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) for all the conditional jumps.

Comment: So al will minus cl; if al was positive and bigger than cl you would get positive, thus no jump. But if al was positive and small than cl, then you would get negative thus jump. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (except for "al will minus cl", which I interpret as if al was modified, while it isn't -- sorry, I'm not a native speaker of English)

Comment: The code samples as posted look like AT&T syntax though?

Comment: This is most certainly AT&T syntax.